# What is "components" in "boot=live components splash quiet"

Tags: boot

It appears in `/isolinux/menu.cfg` in debian live-usb iso.

```
APPEND initrd=/live/initrd.img-4.19.0-5-amd64 boot=live components splash quiet
```

This doesn't seem to be a [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html).
I wasn't luckier in debian documentation either.
The genericness of the term has defeated my google-fu.

This menu.cfg file being generated hinders search as well.

Comment: It's kernel parameters

Comment: Thanks, but... what?

Comment: SE don't support complex rich text in comment, but most web browser support web page scaling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "components" boot parameter is provided by the [live-config](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=live-config&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) package on Debian. The [live-config(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/live-config-doc/live-config.7) on Debian Manpages had mentioned this boot parameter.

> **Boot Parameters (components)**
>
> **live-config** is only activated if 'boot=live' is used as a boot parameter. Additionally, **live-config** needs to be told which components to run through the 'live-config.components' parameter or which components to not run through the 'live-config.nocomponents' parameter. If both 'live-config.components' and 'live-config.nocomponents' are used, or, if either one is specified multiple times, always the later one takes precedence over the previous one(s).
>
> **live-config.components | components**
>   All components are run. This is what live images use by default [...]

Debian Live CD uses such boot parameter by default and usually specified in `boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `isolinux/menu.cfg` of the ISO image (naming and path may vary).

The boot parameter `boot=live components` is also used for other Live CD variants, which can be found as [DebianLive/MultibootISO](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianLive/MultibootISO) and [BootUsbWithGrubRescue](https://wiki.debian.org/BootUsbWithGrubRescue) on Debian Wiki.

Comment: Wow! Clear, complete and sourced! Thanks.